# Python: Monkey-patching a library constant

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm writing a client for a slightly non-compliant STOMP server. STOMP 1.1 allows a connection to be started with either a `STOMP` or a `CONNECT` command, but at the moment the server can only accept `CONNECT`, and the library - `stomp.py` - can only sends `STOMP`. Connecting with `STOMP` makes the server emit a messagebox with an error.

This can be easily fixed by altering the library - it's a one-line change from `cmd = CMD_STOMP` to `cmd = CMD_CONNECT`, or to redefine `CMD_STOMP = "CONNECT"`. However I'd rather monkey-patch the constant and leave the library unaltered. Is this possible?

This doesn't work:

```py
import stomp

stomp.constants.CMD_STOMP = "CONNECT"

conn = stomp.Connection11([("localhost", 51515)])
conn.connect() # tries to connect with "STOMP" not "CONNECT"
```

Nor does this:

```py
from stomp import constants
constants.CMD_STOMP = "CONNECT"
from stomp import Connection11

conn = Connection11([("localhost", 51515)])
conn.connect()
```

This Medium article gives an example: https://medium.com/@chipiga86/python-monkey-patching-like-a-boss-87d7ddb8098e

```
from stomp import constants
constants.CMD_STOMP = "CONNECT"
uncache(['stomp.constants'])
from stomp import Connection11
...
```

However `uncache` seems to not exist and I can find no evidence anywhere else that it exists.

Comment: `uncache` is a function mentioned in the Medium article. Look at https://gist.github.com/schipiga/482de016fa749bc08c7b36cf5323fd1b#file-uncache-py.

Comment: @Vishnudev... apparently my reading comprehension has gone out the window today, can't believe I missed that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Almost always the solution to your problem is right infront of your face. Happens. @Jack

Comment: Turns out, if you visit medium.com with umatrix running on default settings, it will not load any frames from github :D

Comment: Ofcourse, because of `iframe`. @Jack

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the function in the Medium article as my browser settings blocked the Github frame:

https://gist.github.com/schipiga/482de016fa749bc08c7b36cf5323fd1b/

```py
import sys

def uncache(exclude):
    """Remove package modules from cache except excluded ones.
    On next import they will be reloaded.
    
    Args:
        exclude (iter<str>): Sequence of module paths.
    """
    pkgs = []
    for mod in exclude:
        pkg = mod.split('.', 1)[0]
        pkgs.append(pkg)

    to_uncache = []
    for mod in sys.modules:
        if mod in exclude:
            continue

        if mod in pkgs:
            to_uncache.append(mod)
            continue

        for pkg in pkgs:
            if mod.startswith(pkg + '.'):
                to_uncache.append(mod)
                break

    for mod in to_uncache:
        del sys.modules[mod]
```

By running this function in the demo script I set up to illustrate this question and adding a `print` statement, I can get an exact list of the modules to delete after setting the constant:

```
import sys
from stomp import constants

constants.CMD_STOMP = "CONNECT"

del sys.modules["stomp"]
del sys.modules["stomp.adapter"]
del sys.modules["stomp.connect"]
del sys.modules["stomp.protocol"]
del sys.modules["stomp.utils"]
del sys.modules["stomp.exception"]
del sys.modules["stomp.listener"]
del sys.modules["stomp.logging"]
del sys.modules["stomp.transport"]

import stomp

conn = stomp.Connection11([("localhost", 51515)])
conn.connect()
```

This is obviously brittle; putting the function into my codebase temporarily would be more robust.

Comment: Pleased to say this code got to run at least three times before the server update was released, fixing the original problem